# How to change control's style during its lifetime

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

let's assume we have a control that has it's own style set in Resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Test label" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem: For example - I want to let user decice which background color should the button background have - in time when the control is already displayed over the layout.

Editing style within xaml won't work becase then it must be reapplied to control - it's StaticResource so it will never do that.
Is there any way to force the control to reapply the style?

Setting style in code won't work either unless there is a way to just get existing style and change only one property leaving the rest intact intead of manually copying/setting them. Don't think that reapplying style this way in case I have more than one control is a good idea.

Ideal way: 1) get the style from ResourceDictionary 2) change one property within this style 3) call Control.RefreshStyle() method that will make the control look for a style and apply it again.

Any ideas how to do in clean way? Styles are stored in ResourceDictionaries and it must remain this way. How can I change/modify them and then force controls to apply new style?

Please note, that creating var style = new Style(); then manually adding style.AddValue(...); and setting control.Style = style; is not the solution for me. I have way too many styles and too many controls.

edit: 
Please note 2: I am using UWP, not WPF so all solutions based on DynamicResource won't work for me

Comment: http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.hu/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html

Comment: I don't have DynamicResource in UWP

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is about having 1 Key for many target styles (let's say for example `x:key="ButtonStyleKey"` for a Button Control) and you should have one or many resource dictionary (xaml files ) defining that key in different ways. And when you need to change the style, you have to reload your resource dictionary in your (page,window widget.. whatever `UIElement` you are using)

**Update**

You can do the following:

```
var resDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resDictionary.Source = new Uri("CustomResourceDictionary.xaml",UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resDictionary);
```

I have to mention also that only ThemeResource (DynamicResource in WPF) will take the changes. StaticResources no.

```
<Button Content="Test label" Style="{ThemeResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by reloading resource dictionary? I have 2 resource dictionaries, each with the same key defined and when I use this key to set style for control it uses the one from the last dictionary defined.

Comment: @RTDev could you please have a look at my update. That could be helpful :)

Comment: Hoping you mean anything except that ;) It will not update my layout - don't have DynamicResource in UWP :(

Comment: hmmm Dynamic resources are is in WPF :D. Let's try to find an equivalent

Comment: Hey @RTDev I guess (from my quick reading) that [ThemeResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension) is the equivalent of DynamicResource in WPF. So you can use it

Comment: Yeep, found it too. Now I am trying to use them - cause it is not so obvious and is very poorly documented in case of switching beetwen them. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: It seems that XAML used in WPF is more flexible than UWP one. Hope it goes fine with your issue